# onchange disable textarea php

Tags: javascript

This is my form and i need to disable the textarea if the option city2 is selected and enable the textarea if the other options are selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var citySelect = document.getElementById('city'),
    descriptionTextarea = document.getElementById('description');

citySelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    descriptionTextarea.disabled = citySelect.selectedIndex == 1;
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
<select name="city" id="city">
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
<option value="city3">city3</option>
</select><br />
<br />

<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If comparing by a numerical index is fine...

```
var citySelect = document.getElementById('city'),
    descriptionTextarea = document.getElementById('description');

citySelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    descriptionTextarea.disabled = citySelect.selectedIndex == 1;
}, false);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5mH6/).

If you'd rather compare to the `value` attribute of each option...

```
var citySelect = document.getElementById('city'),
    descriptionTextarea = document.getElementById('description');

citySelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    descriptionTextarea.disabled = citySelect.options[citySelect.selectedIndex].value == 'city2';
}, false);​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pXu8/).

Note too that < IE9 doesn't support `addEventListener()`, just `attachEvent()`. You'll need to define both or use a helper function.

If you end up using jQuery, it can be made more terse...

```
var descriptionTextarea = $('#description');
$('#city').change(function() {
   descriptionTextarea.prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 'city2');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJkrD/).

Comment: Please see my updated question. It doesn't work for me even in mozilla. I couldn't track why?

Comment: @designersvsoft Check out the fiddle. It shows it working, and should be easy to adapt to your code.

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you can do something like:

```
$.ready(function() {
  $('#city').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#city').val() == 'city2')
    {
      $('#description').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#description').attr('disabled', '');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Whilst it could be achieved with jQuery, the OP hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: @alex - true, but its not excluded either. jQuery *is* javascript.

Comment: You'd hardly add jQuery to achieve this one piece of functionality though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript function

```
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
<select name="city" id="city" onchange="checkCity();">
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
<option value="city3">city3</option>
</select><br />
<br />

<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCity() {
    ct = $("#city option:selected").val();
    if(ct=="city2") {
        document.getElementById("description").disabled=true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("description").disabled=false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in the question.